# Importing from CSV and splitting column

Tags: powershell

I have an odd one, I have a little script which pulls out vm information from Azure. It then adds them into a CSV and in the data disk column it split them using **

I thought I could then import the csv and split (based on **) to get each data disk.

the format of the CS is Name, OSdisk, Datadisk under Datadisk they are listed as below

disk1 ** disk2 ** disk3 ** disk4

How would I be able to isolate that column and split it based on **

I thought something like

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\temp\vminfo.csv" 
$list = $csv | select -Property Name, Datadisk 
$list.split('**')
```

But that doesn't work, would appreciate some pointers please :)

Thanks :)

Comment: I added name after -property by mistake there.. :(

Comment: Will the number of datadisks be the same for every VM?

Comment: Also, posting a couple of rows of data (with headers) would be super helpful. Be sure to sanitize any private data.

Comment: Also, also, you can edit your question to take Name out if it is not supposed to be there.

Comment: @EBGreen  thanks Ed didn’t know I could edit question after posting .. will bear that in mind for the future .. the number of disks vary on each vm, which is why I’ve had to split them using the two asterisk

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data after you split that string?

Comment: I@EBGreen  into a text file or csv, either works cos we need to check to see if they are encrypted and sizes etc, basically further analysis, it’s part of our ongoing improvement and cost reduction exercise

Comment: Well, jagged field counts will break the CSV standard. I think this will get you headed in the right direction but without knowing more about what you are doing it is hard to give you a good answer: $list = $csv | %{$_.DataDisk.Split('*') | ?{$_ -ne ''}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always happy to help the silver surfer ;)

try this:

```
import-csv "c:\temp\vminfo.csv" | %{
$current=$_
$_.Datadisk.Split('**') | where {$_ -ne ''} | %{[pscustomobject]@{Name=$current.Name;Disk=$_.trim()}}
}
```